Estou com uma dificuldade com listas suspensas no Excel
Eu estou com uma dúvida aqui porque minhas habilidades no Excel são bem básicas. Eu estou fazendo uma escala onde eu queria puxar de uma planilha para outra alguns dados, porém esses dados necessitam seguir alguns critérios, o primeiro deles seria selecionar uma data (até aqui eu faço de boa), esse seria o gatilho para carregar os dados, que seria os nomes das pessoas que estão marcadas para trabalhar naquele dia, excluindo as pessoas que estão com marcações diferentes, não sei se ficou claro, mas basicamente seria, eu seleciono uma data e é listado para mim todas as pessoas escaladas para trabalhar naquele dia, se alguém puder me  dar uma ajuda eu agradeço muito. Imagens e arquivos disponíveis, é só pedir.
